# Stored procedure conversion failed

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure where I have 3 "dynamic" parameters, first is an `int` and the second and third are `datetime`.

How the output looks like:

```
17 | 2016-01-24 11:28:22.233 | 2016-05-22 09:07:04.220
```

Due to my final application that is connecting to this stored procedure, I have to treat the date time values as `nvarchar` to be able to use the `LIKE` operator, so that the user can easily filter the throw those date time's

What I have done is to create query that works fine gets back the wanted output

```
SELECT * 
FROM WATCHDOG.WatchdogUsr.WebsiteFailureLog
WHERE websiteID  = 17
  AND (((CONVERT(NVARCHAR(45), FailureLogStart, 121) LIKE '%2016-01%')))
```

But my stored procedure has an issue:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure WatchDogDataCollector, Line 5
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[WatchDogDataCollector] 
    @websiteID int = NULL, 
    @FailureLogStart NVARCHAR = NULL
AS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM WATCHDOG.WatchdogUsr.WebsiteFailureLog
    WHERE websiteID  = ISNULL(@websiteID,websiteID) 
      AND (((CONVERT(NVARCHAR(45), FailureLogStart, 121) LIKE '%'+@FailureLogStart+'%')))
```

Table schema:

[image]

Comment: pls post your table schema...

Comment: `@FailureLogStart` is of type `datetime` - you can't pass partial dates values to it like `2016-01`. You need to change the data type to `varchar`.

Comment: @MitchWheat maid an update

Comment: @ZoharPeled Well I dot that with this line (((CONVERT(NVARCHAR(45), FailureLogStart, 121)  or not ?

Comment: don;t change datetime column to varchar. that would be very stupid!

Comment: No, this line converts the DateTime column to nvarchar(45), you need to also change the data type of the parameter.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I have done that but now the output of the stored procedure behaves like its not filtering simply getting back everything btw I have update the code

Comment: @MitchWheat Emm I have to this is the only way to handle a "like" functionally witch is a must have in my application

Comment: Or let your users tell you what part of the date they are entering and build a valid date from the input.

Comment: @ZoharPeled well not possible since at the end its going to be a report applicaiton and if the user for example wants to see only to 2016 dates you can not recreate a date from that

Comment: If the user enters 2016, you return all the dates >= '2016-01-01' and < '2017-01-01'... the hard part is to figure out how to translate the user input into date.

Comment: @ZoharPeled thanks for the effort but no this will not work

Comment: @Nico: " I have to this is the only way to handle a "like" functionally" -incorrect.

Comment: @MitchWheat Willing to elaborate with me ?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `(n)varchar` variables and parameters that you use  - in the case of a stored procedure parameter, omitting the length results in a parameter of **exactly ONE character length!** which is typically **NOT** what you intended.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you can't figure out what date part(s) the user enters, your only option is indeed to cast the datetime value to a string:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[WatchDogDataCollector] 
    @websiteID int = NULL, 
    @FailureLogStart VARCHAR(23) = NULL
AS 
SELECT * 
FROM WATCHDOG.WatchdogUsr.WebsiteFailureLog
WHERE websiteID  = ISNULL(@websiteID,websiteID) 
AND (((CONVERT(CHAR(23), FailureLogStart, 121) LIKE '%'+@FailureLogStart+'%')))
```

Note: the number of chars in a string representing datetime with style 121 is 23. there is no point in casting to nvarchar(45).

Comment: I just wanted to tell you that you gave me the answer in the comments !! thanks allot for your time and effort :)